# How to put dynamic date filter in TDE?

Tags: xquery, marklogic-10

In "context" how to use date function? I want to keep the triples only for last 10 days of the doc ingested in ML.

```
<template xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde">
  <context>/MedlineCitation[createDate > ( fn:currentDateTime() - xs:dayTimeDuration('P10D')]</context>
  <triples>
    <triple>
      <subject>
        <val>sem:iri(concat(ForeName,' ',LastName))</val>
      </subject>
      <predicate>
        <val>sem:iri('authored')</val>
      </predicate>
      <object>
        <val>xs:string(../../ArticleTitle)</val>
      </object>
    </triple>
  </triples>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is [`fn:current-dateTime()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2005/CR-xpath-functions-20051103/#func-current-dateTime), not `fn:currentDateTime()`, and you are missing the ending `)`:

```
/MedlineCitation[createDate > ( fn:current-dateTime() - xs:dayTimeDuration('P10D') )]
```

However, after correcting the code you will then find that it returns `XDMP-UNINDEXABLEPATH`.

There are restrictions and limitations for what are allowable expressions and functions for an indexable path expression. See: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/xquery/xpath#id_18473

For a list of Functions Callable in Predicate Expressions, see:
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/xquery/xpath#id_51541

A [Query Base View](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/OpticAPI#id_90507) that calculates date logic at runtime might be a more appropriate means of implementing the dynamic date filter and integrating with your TDE.

Comment: Still it does not work. That was typo, in actual code I am using the correct functions, still it throws error like "UNINDEXABLEPATH"

Comment: it is dateTime format.

Comment: okay, now I see. Your issue is wanting to have a date criteria for filter that is not static. I don't think you can do that. There are restrictions on the context XPath. To test whether some path expression is an indexable path expression, use `cts:valid-index-path()`.

Comment: But is there any way to do that?

Comment: No.  Applying a TDE is essentially enriching the index.  The index is a rather static data structure, provisioned at ingestion, and used when querying.  I see 2 alternatives: i) create a range index on the date and add the extra criterion at query time, or ii) base the TDE on some kind of flag, itself based on the date, and have an external process (a batch running every day) setting the flag based on the date (changing the flag on the document will trigger reindexing.)